# jQuery Toggle Duplication Stops Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just setup jQuery Toggle. Here's the function below. it works fine. Basically when you click 'Show More' it shows more content, and the word 'Show More' changes to 'Show Less'.

```
$('#toggle').toggle(
        function() {
            $('#content').slideDown();
            $(this).html('Show less &rarr;');
        }, 
        function() { 
            $('#content').slideUp(); 
            $(this).html('Show more &rarr;');
        }
    );
```

This is fine, my issue is having more than one on a page. For some reason when I copy and paste the same HTML multiple times to create more than one toggle content, the others don't work and only the first one does. Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="team-page">

    Intro paragraph

    <a id="toggle" href="#">Show more &rarr;</a>

    <div id="content">
    Content shown when toggled
    </div>
</div>
```

So when I duplicate this multiple times, the rest don't work. There is the obvious get around by adding #toggle1 #toggle2 and duplicating and amending the jQuery - but what's the better way? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#toggle').toggle( ...
```

You just get the 1st element because you're using the **ID** selector. and id is unique .
You need to use a **CLASS** 'content' :

```
<div class="content">
</div>
```

and transform your code :

```
$('.toggle').toggle( ...
```

Comment: *Kicks self* - damn I knew it'd be that obvious.